# sorting html in shell script

Tags: html, shell, sorting

I have a file with an html code inside it

[image]

Is there a way to sort the content by names? such that the file is now sorted like:

[image]

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply run this command :

```
sort -t '>' -k 3 filename
```

I think you have an error in your wanted output : *Chan* should be before *deLtorro*.

By the way, can you tell us what are you trying to achieve finally ? Maybe that's not the better way.

Comment: Wait! it does work!Thank you so much. But can you explain what's happening?

Comment: "does not work" is quite too vague. It works for me, sorted like this : Chan, delTorro, Palonde, Sanchez (alphabetic order...)

Comment: nah I took off one of the ">" after br, trying all different sorts of ways to sort it haha

Comment: Dunno what you are trying, but seems odd anyway. It it's for convenience, it's ok, if it's for a webpage, it's wrong.